# How to use the Suricata IDS to monitor the entire network?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, monitoring

I have the following 3 PCs connected to a router via Ethernet:

PC1 – 192.168.1.101 (Linux Ubuntu)

PC2 – 192.168.1.100 (Windows)

PC3 – 192.168.1.1 (Windows)

All PCs can ping each other.

PC1 has Suricata installed in IDS mode. It has a simple ping rule included:

```
alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"PING detected"; sid:2; rev:1;)
```

I launch Suricata be entering the following command in PC1:

```
suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i eth3
```

eth3 is the main Ethernet interface in PC1.

The ping rule is triggered when I ping PC1 from PC2 and PC3, and the appropriate message is recorded in the log file. This rule is also triggered when I ping PC2 and PC3 from PC1.

However, this rule is not triggered when I ping PC2 from PC3 and vice versa. Suricata listens only on eth3 interface in PC1. The traffic doesn’t pass through PC1 when I ping PC2 from PC3, even though all 3 PCs are on the same network.

Is it possible to configure Suricata to monitor the entire network and not only the PC it is installed on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethernet switches do not broadcast all traffic to all ports.

A unicast exchange between two hosts on two separate switch ports will not be seen by a listening host on a third switch port under normal operating conditions.

More expensive managed switches, with enterprise functions such as VLAN support often have port mirroring features, that serve as a wiretap utility that duplicates all traffic sent or received on any one port to a second designated port.  Depending on the switch make and model, there may be caveats to this function that may make the designated port less functional, ie: only able to receive traffic, not send, while the mirroring is active.

Another caveat that is likely on all but the most powerful, expensive switches, is that only one port can be mirrored at one time.  For a 3 node switched network, that's not a problem, as if one or the other port is mirrored, either destination the host on the unmonitored port can talk to, is monitored.  A 4 node network, however, would leave two ports unmonitored.

In an Internet Gateway situation, port mirroring would be turned on between the router and the switch, and so would catch all Internet-sourced traffic, but not all LAN traffic.

There may exist switches that can mirror all VLAN or all backplane traffic to a designated port, but I'm not familiar with such functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, Nevin. I am very new to networking, so it's good to know about the port mirroring feature that switches can have. I only have access to a cheap USRobotics router. So I assume I will not be able to solve my problem without a decent switch.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at the Netgear pro switches like:

GS105Ev2 – 5-Port Gigabit ProSAFE Plus Switch

They are pretty cheap and support a port mirror setup. Place the switch between your router and the rest of the network for internet visibility.