# How to use the Suricata IDS to monitor the entire network?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, suricata

I have the following 3 PCs connected to a router via Ethernet:

PC1 – 192.168.1.101 (Linux Ubuntu)

PC2 – 192.168.1.100 (Windows)

PC3 – 192.168.1.1 (Windows)

All PCs can ping each other.

PC1 has Suricata installed in IDS mode. It has a simple ping rule included:

```
alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"PING detected"; sid:2; rev:1;)
```

I launch Suricata be entering the following command in PC1:

```
suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i eth3
```

eth3 is the main Ethernet interface in PC1:

[image]

The ping rule is triggered when I ping PC1 from PC2 and PC3, and the appropriate message is recorded in the log file. This rule is also triggered when I ping PC2 and PC3 from PC1.

However, this rule is not triggered when I ping PC2 from PC3 and vice versa. Suricata listens only on eth3 interface in PC1. The traffic doesn’t pass through PC1 when I ping PC2 from PC3, even though all 3 PCs are on the same network.

Is it possible to configure Suricata to monitor the entire network and not only the PC it is installed on?

Comment: Is your router acting as a switch and preventing PC1 from seeing the traffic? This is not a Suricata problem, but a very basic networking design problem.

Comment: I realised that I need a good switch that supports port mirroring, so that it can send all the traffic to PC1 for inspection. I only have a cheap router that doesn't support that feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the Suricata IDS to monitor the entire network?](http://superuser.com/questions/785635/how-to-use-the-suricata-ids-to-monitor-the-entire-network)